# Why JSX Transform is deprecated? What is the advantage of using Babel over JSX transform?

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

Since i have started reading react, I learnt about JSX and Babel. Before Babel, JSX transformer [React tools] were used to convert JFX syntax to browser understandable format. Now Babel takes over its place. My point is , Why they replaced JFX transformer? Does it had any disadvantages?

Comment: babel include JSX transform and Es6 feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Babel has advantages such as being able to integrate with a variety of other tools, and being able to compile ES6 code. There was a post by FB here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html

And there's a few articles scattered around if you Google. Basically a lot of webapps use Babel, it's awesome and does JSX transformation as well as all the other JS compiling